# Average precision, balanced accuracy, F1-score, Matthews Correlation Coefficient, geometric means

Tags: machine-learning, metric

Average precision, balanced accuracy, F1-score, Matthews Correlation Coefficient, geometrics means are the few evaluation metrics for imbalanced data. However, all this metrics can lead to different 'best' model. How do we then decide which is indeed the 'best' model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's about **designing the task** properly. I'm not talking about the design of the model, and this is not either about selecting an evaluation based on the characteristics of the data (e.g. there's no simple way to decide based on whether the data is imbalanced or not).

The design of standard tasks is usually established in the state of the art. Take machine translation (MT) for example, there is a whole area of research devoted to evaluating MT, with various simple and advanced evaluation measures designed specifically for the task.

People often confuse 'standard type of task' and 'standard task', for example assuming that all the classification tasks can be evaluated the same way. Of course there are standard measures which are used very often in classification, but even with "regular" classification one should ensure that the evaluation measure fits the task.

So how does one select the "best" evaluation measure for a task, when the task is not standard? First it's important to realize that a performance score is always a simplification, so there's no perfect evaluation (btw this is why it's sometimes relevant to use several measures). The goal of the evaluation is to represent how well the model does the job, whatever the job is. This often implies human annotations, sometimes by experts, in order to represent what the job should be about. Depending on the task, it is sometimes relevant to compare different evaluation measures: what are their similarities, differences, possible biases or limitations, and which one fits the target task the best.

In short: there is no simple answer for evaluation, it's not about applying technical rules but about analyzing the specific target task.

Comment: Thanks @Erwan for your insight. Can I interpret 'task' as business use case?

Comment: @gracenz yes, absolutely. By 'task' I mean the intended application, taking into account the context, constraints, expectations, etc.